# How to initialize variables in a session scoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have two booleans that controls the render of some components, the problem is that the variables saves there last state until the session expires, i

```
<f:facet name="footer">
  <p:commandButton action="#{personBean.report}" ajax="false" value="Publish"
                            rendered="#{personBean.reportMode}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
  <p:commandButton action="#{personBean.saveEditing}" ajax="false" value="Save"
                            rendered="#{personBean.editMode}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
</f:facet>
```

the bean is session scoped and has the following attributes:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "personBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ReportPerson {
private boolean editMode;
private boolean reportMode;

}
```

the bean contains these method that changes the values of the booleans:

```
public String editPerson() {
    System.err.println("Edit Missing Person");
    editMode = true;
    reportMode = false;
    return "ReportNewPerson";
}
```

the problem is that these values remains until the session expires and as a result the components renders incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a session scoped bean then you should Initialize them in constructor like

```
public ReportPerson(){
//let say you want to show report mode by default
editMode = false;
reportMode = true;
}
```

after then , create two methods like

```
public void inEditMode(){
           editMode = true;
           reportMode = false;
}

public void inReportMode(){
           editMode = false;
           reportMode = true;
}
```

Now call `#{reportPerson.editMode}` and `#{reportPerson.reportMode}` on your rendering cpomponent and call these methods `inReportMode()` and `inEditMode` by getting bean from `sessionmap` in your backing bean.You may get bean from sessionmap like this

```
ReportPerson rp = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("reportPerson");
```

From this , you can get current bean and from this you can invoke

```
rp.inEditMode();
```

As by using session scope , you have to change them by your logic because they will keep their state remain during the whole session.

Comment: ok where i could call triggerReportMode() i want to call these method when the user reports a new person, in another word how to explicitly call the constructor of a session scoped bean ?

Comment: The constructor is automatically called when the bean object gets created, the JSF framework takes care of that. But, I would not suggest to initialize anything within the constructor of a bean, do it within an `private void init()` (name and scope of the methods can be chosen by you) method which is annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: @Manuel nice suggestion :) but can you explain the pros and cons of init method over constructor

Comment: Within an init method annotated with @PostConstruct, you have your managedbeans injected already. E.g. If in you would have a reference to `someRandomBean` in your `personBean` injected (via @ManagedProperty), the reference won`t be available within the constructor of the `personBean`, but it would be in the init method.